# Stata: Predicted values in autoregressive system

Tags: stata, prediction, autoregressive

I'm trying to replicate the results from [Yagan (2016, pp 8-11)](http://eml.berkeley.edu/~yagan/EnduringImpact.pdf). There, the following autoregressive system is run:

[image: regression]

The author then runs this system based on data until 2007. Then, he computes `\Delta \tilde \log E_st`, minus the predicted values `\hat\Delta \tilde \log E_st`, for `s>2007`.

I'm wondering how to do this in Stata. I've run the regression on `(2.1)` as follows:

```
xtreg emp_log_diff_difference  L.emp_log_diff_difference L2.emp_log_diff_difference L.emp_labor_log_difference L2.emp_labor_log_difference L.labor_pop_lo
> g_difference L2.labor_pop_log_difference if year < 2008, fe

Fixed-effects (within) regression               Number of obs     =     47,066
Group variable: fipsnumeric                     Number of groups  =      3,140

R-sq:                                           Obs per group:
     within  = 0.9669                                         min =          6
     between = 0.9999                                         avg =       15.0
     overall = 0.9998                                         max =         15

                                                F(6,43920)        =  213557.01
corr(u_i, Xb)  = 0.9477                         Prob > F          =     0.0000

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 emp_log_diff_difference |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
 emp_log_diff_difference |
                     L1. |   1.003307   .0021437   468.03   0.000      .999105    1.007508
                     L2. |  -.0260857   .0018339   -14.22   0.000    -.0296801   -.0224913
                         |
emp_labor_log_difference |
                     L1. |   -1.02951   .0068332  -150.66   0.000    -1.042903   -1.016117
                     L2. |   .9339031   .0068993   135.36   0.000     .9203803    .9474259
                         |
labor_pop_log_difference |
                     L1. |  -.9333421   .0019235  -485.24   0.000    -.9371122   -.9295721
                     L2. |   .9203601   .0022397   410.92   0.000     .9159702    .9247501
                         |
                   _cons |   .2127899   .0110194    19.31   0.000     .1911917    .2343881
-------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
                 sigma_u |  .03754957
                 sigma_e |  .01468425
                     rho |   .8673551   (fraction of variance due to u_i)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
F test that all u_i=0: F(3139, 43920) = 8.73                 Prob > F = 0.0000
```

But here's where I'm stuck now. How exactly do I predict the value for 2008 — I need to somehow feed in the actual sequence of data for each `s`?

**I tried**

```
predict emp_log_diff_difference_pred
gen fluctuation = mp_log_diff_difference - mp_log_diff_difference_pred
```

However, it appears that the predictions for 2008 are exactly on top of the actual outcomes?

```
. su emp_log_diff_difference_pred if year == 2008

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
emp_log_di~d |      3,137    9.309528     1.42701   3.581492   15.06468

. su fluctuation if year == 2008

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 fluctuation |      3,137           0           0          0          0
```

Comment: Using the data for 2007 and estimated coefficients you can predict the LHS variable of 2.1 for 2008 (it's an autoregressive model after all). Then you can use this prediction and the estimated coefficients of 2.2 to predict the LHS of 2.2 for 2008, and do the same for 2.3.  Iteratively, you can predict the LHS of 2.1 for 2009 using the previous predictions, etc. In stata, you can probably use the predict command: http://www.stata.com/manuals13/u20.pdf p.17

Comment: The fact that you explain so much variance with your specification is puzzling. Is there a table in the paper you're tring to replicate that corresponds to the table for your Fixed-effects (within) regression? I'm curious to see how they differ. Moreover it looks like those processes are I(1). Please post in the comment to notify when you made an edit to your post.

Comment: @dv_bn Unfortunately, there is no table in the paper with any intermediate outcome.

Comment: I'm surprised each equation is estimated separately from the rest of the system. The entire empirical strategy is based on Blanchard and Katz (1992), have you tried to have a look at it?